# What's the difference between Color.RED (as in capitalized) and Color.red?

Tags: java, swing, colors

Is there any difference between the `Color.RED` variable and the `Color.red` variable, or `Color.BLUE` and `Color.blue` variable (or any other color) from the Java Swing `Color` class?

I can't find what the difference is, nor do I notice any. Isn't having both just redundant? (I realize i'm probably overlooking something simple)

Just curious.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that before. Thank you for the link! Okay... so it's just the naming convention, should I just delete this thread then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None; the first version was with lower case so it remained there for backwards compatibility. The capital letter version was added to respect Java Naming Convention.

Comment: Yeah got it now (didn't see the duplicate question posted earlier)... wasn't aware that the naming convention was different back then.

Comment: The naming convention wasn't different, was absent. As far as I know AWT (from where `Color` class comes from) is from version 1 which would mean 1995 and the code conventions firstly appeared only in 1997.